# Asp.net MVC client validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, ajax.beginform

I am building asp.net mvc5 application and don't have enough knowledge to solve it. I have a form which needs to be validated and then post using ajax. I use `Ajax.BeginForm()`

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActionMethod", "Controller", new { id =
 "form"}, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnBegin =
 "FormValidation", OnSuccess = "WriteMessage" }))
```

Inside function FormValidation I have my own validation code where, among other things, i have made an ajax call to fetch data from database. If function returns false form is not submited but if returns true form is submitted. I successfully get the data in json format. My fetched data is inside success callback from ajax and can't be used outside it so inside success callback i have validation code. But when my validation code inside success callback fails i want that form isn't submitted but that error is shown to user.  How to stop form from being submitted or perhaps there is another way of doing this.

My controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="ID,Date,Name,Surname,Adress,ProjectName")] Data data)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Data.Add(data);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(data);

        }
```

Comment: show complete form and controller action

Comment: If you're using an Ajax call, you're not performing client-side validation as you're communicating with the server. What you should be doing is decorating your Model properties with some attributes to tell the Textboxes (or other inputs) valid ranges, etc of the individual properties. You can then also perform additional minor business logic on the different values in the click method on your Submit button before sending the form data to the server. The method that you provided for your Ajax is nothing but a Save method. No validation.

Comment: yes but what about with some 'complicated' scenarios. I know i can create my own custom annotations but i don't know if i would be able to do it for my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

why you not use dataannotations ??

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-6

try this because using Dataannotations you can handle both client side and server side validations

so please try ....

Comment: yes I know about data annotations but i would need some custom annotations for my scenario and i don't think that I would be able to do it on that way. for example i have four textboxes and i have different options how that textboxes need to be filled according to database(let's say modifying some object in database) i.e. user enter first and third textbox and other two are empty so i need to validate is this good entry. That's what i was trying to do with ajax call..but obviously i will need to do something else...thanks for feedback ;)